# VimL: How to send lines to clipboard?

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm a Newbie to vim scripting. I already searched the help pages, but might not search for the right key word.

I've written a small function to get two certain line numbers:

```
let l:pattern  = '^#%%'
let l:start    = search(l:pattern, 'Wb')
let l:end      = search(l:pattern,'W')
if l:end == 0
    let l:end = line('$')
end
let lines = getline(start,end)
```

I want to write the lines in range[start, end] to the clipboard.
How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your Vim is built with clipboard support (`:echo has('clipboard')` returns `1`), then you can put text in either register `*` (selection/right-click) or register `+` (Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V) with:

```
let @+ = 'foo'
let @* = 'foo'
```

In a vimscript setting, though, it's best to use `:help setreg()` as it gives you more control over what really goes in the register and how it might be used. In your case, the following command:

```
call setreg('+', lines, 'l')
```

should populate the clipboard register with the content of `lines` and mark it as "linewise".

Or you could do the less elegant but much simpler to reason about:

```
execute l:start . ',' . l:end . 'y +'
```

See `:help :yank` and `:help :range`.

If you don't have clipboard support, then you will have to feed those lines to an external tool like `xclip` on Linux or `pbcopy` on MacOS:

```
execute l:start . ',' . l:end . 'w !pbcopy'
```

See `:help :w_c`.